# Magento 2 full page cache consumes total memory on the server

Tags: apache, caching, magento2, centos7, magento-fpc

I have a magento 2.2 website hosted on a rackspace with OS as centos 7. I was using apache as my webserver. I have enabled full page cache in Magento 2.2

After i enable FPC the Magento_Root_Folder/var/page_cache folder is getting increased so much and this folder is occupying all most all the disk space and finally resulting in website going down with an error "No space left on the device"

Because of the above error, I am now forced to disable full page cache and my website is extremely slow.

Can anyone let me know why after enabling FPC in magento admin panel the cache folder is increasing and is there any solutions for this.

Thanks,
Magento Developer

Comment: We have always used Fpc without these kind of issues, check your technology stack and server parameters if they fits magento needs. Magento is heavy-duty framework, so it is using a lot more resources than your average wordpress website. :)

Comment: @Macas - I am having the same issue, the page_cache folder grows to 25GB overnight and we only have about 400 products on our site. Any solutions?

Comment: Do you use any 3rd party modules or your custom solutions? Because it looks like it is a non-standard solution problem. Since I was worked on multiple projects - non of them had any similar issues. Also I would strongly recommend to upgrade magento, to see if problem persists. 400 Products isn't much at all so it is really strange issue. Sadly I cannot help much more.

Comment: did you find the issue? I am having the same problem for a week now, magento 2.3.5 nothing changed but in 24 hours magento page_cache folder gets to 35gb